# Mongo query that returns unique data in date range

Tags: mongodb

I need to query my users collection for new users that started after the date "2015-11-20" returning only unique emails.

Here's a sample of the structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("abcd123"),
        "user_name" : "My Name",
        "last_name" : "Name",
        "first_name" : "My",
        "email" : "my.name@gmail.com",
        "user_type" : "general",
        "joining_date" : ISODate("2015-11-20T14:56:57.165Z")
}
```

Here's my query thus far, I'm not sure how it's making sure, if even, that only unique emails are returned.

```
db.users.aggregate([{$match: {"joining_date": {$gt: ISODate("2015-11-20")}}},{$group: {_id:{email: "$email", "first_name": "$first_name", "last_name": "$last_name", "user_name": "$user_name"}}}]).pretty();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of aggregation you can use [`distinct`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/distinct/) method of collection. So from the above example your distinct query will look like:

```
db.users.distinct('email', {"joining_date": {$gt: ISODate("2015-11-20")}}
```

The above query returns an array of email based on the condition.

Your aggregation query wont return you unique emails as you are grouping by email, user_name, first_name and last_name. This will return the unique combination of them. If you were only grouping by email then you will get the unique mail ids. But then all the mail ids will be in separate document and you need to iterate over the result set. There is a similar aggregate query similar to the distinct method shown above.

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {$match: {"joining_date": {$gt: ISODate("2015-11-20")}}},
  {$group: {_id:null, emailIds: {$addToSet : "$email"}}}
])
```

Answer (score 1):

````
 db.collectionName.aggregate([
 {$group:{_id:"$distinctcolumnname", count: {$sum:1}}},
 { $match:{"datecolumnname": { $gte : "21-08-2016 00:00:00" ,$lte :"21-08-2016 09:59:59"}}}]);```
````